# How to generate a matrix base on a function in matlab?

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

I have a function `pr_trans(i, j)` that gives value base on value of i and j.

How can I use it generate a 27*27 matrix, where the value of `i_th` row and `j_th` column is given by `pr_trans(i, j)`?

27*27 because i and j fall between 1-27.

Comment: Use a `for` loop, or better [vectorize](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/vectorization.html) the function if it lends itself to. If you want help with that, define your function exactly in your question

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question to properly inline format your code samples so that it renders properly - please see the editing help for more information on formatting. Also please note that non constructive text such as 'thank you' is not necessaary in SO. Last, I would recommend you to edit the question and possibly provide more info on what you have tried. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with loops:

```
Data = Nan(27,27);

for i = 1 : 27
   for j = 1:27
     Data(i,j) = pr_trans(i, j) ;
   end
end
```